# Http 504 gateway timeout apache 2.4.6

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-504

Getting 504 gateway timeout in response if the server takes more than 60 secs, process on the server keeps running and complete its execution but on client side getting response 504 gateway timeout of 60 secs so suspecting apache not waiting for PHP to complete its execution and sending gateway timeout response.

Read somewhere that can't increase timeout for apache 2.4.6 it is a known bug for that particular version, so can't try out by increasing the timeout for Apache. My site is running over https and any request that is taking more than 60 sec processing fro php side, getting response gateway timeout 504.

Note: No proxy and no load balancer is there, the server is setup on Amazon EC2 and running (LAMP: Linux CentOS 7, Apache 2.4.6, MySQL 5.7, PHP 5.6)

Comment: If php and server continue to work but your browser display timeout it's ok for you ?

Comment: how run php - php-apache-module  php-cgi   php-fmp  ?

Comment: @FAEWZX php-apache-module

Comment: @Xenofexs, No that is an issue and looking solution for that here

Comment: Was this resolved? I'm facing the same issue, client getting 504 from server after 60 seconds although PHP keeps running and all config is set to 600.

Comment: I found out the problem on my side - it was a load balancer timeout. We're using AWS load balancer and it's default timeout was 60 seconds, this was a pain to catch, hope it could help others.

Answer (score 13):

Increasing the max_execution_time limit in php.ini

```
max_execution_time=600
```

Increase the default timeout value in the httpd.conf

```
Timeout 600
```

At the beginning of the script, start displaying information, for example

```
print " ";
```

continue to send data periodically to maintain the connection

Comment: On AWS EC2 (LAMP) the `Timeout` directive in *httpd.conf* did the trick.

Comment: Timeout wasn't even in my httpd.conf file. Adding it though did the trick!

Comment: Didnt have Timeout in my httpd.conf (Mac os). Added it and that did the magic.